# Using yield in a while loop to return one or many objects

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have two database methods. One fetches one row based on a name and creates an object out of it. The other is almost identical, but it fetches all rows and creates `n` objects out of it. I was hoping to use `yield return` to share the method that process the SQLLite data, but the issue I have is in `CreateFooFromSQLSelect` is telling me `The body of CreateFooFromSQLSelect cannot be an iterator block because`Foo`is not an iterator type`. I really wasn't expecting that.

```
public Foo GetFoo(string name){
   string sql = "SELECT age FROM people WHERE name = " + name;
   return CreateFooFromSelect(sql);
}

public List<Foo> GetFoos(){
   List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>();
   string sql = "SELECT * FROM people";
   foos.Add(CreateFooFromSelect(sql));
}

private Foo CreateFooFromSelect(string sql){
   Foo foo;
   SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, sqlConnection);
   SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
   while(reader.Read()){
        yield return foo = new Foo(reader["age"]);
   }
}
```

Comment: It should return IEnumerable<Foo>, not Foo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `yield` statement only on methods that return `IEnumerable<T>`. In your case method returns `Foo`, so you cannot use `yield` statement there. Instead you can try such approach:

```
private IEnumerable<Foo> CreateFooFromSelect(string sql){
   SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, sqlConnection);
   SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
   while(reader.Read()){
        yield return new Foo(reader["age"]);
   }
}
```

In this case instead of using `Add` you can use `AddRange`:

```
public List<Foo> GetFoos(){
   List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>();
   string sql = "SELECT * FROM people";
   foos.AddRange(CreateFooFromSelect(sql));
}
```

You can read more about [`yield` keyword on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. For single results, do I need to cast to (Foo) ?

Comment: You cannot cast `IEnumerable<Foo>` to `Foo`, however you can use function `FirstOrDefault()` to get the first item of collection

Comment: I don't seem to be able to do that. `return CreateFooFromSelect(sql).FirstOrDefault();`  Oh this is LINQ.

Comment: @user3822370 Do you get any errors? Did you include `using System.Linq;` at the top of the file?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid LINQ. I'll find some other way to get the first element of the result.

Comment: @user3822370 If you don't want to use LINQ then `CreateFooFromSelect(sql)[0]` should do the trick. Keep in mind you will get an exception if there are no items in result set.

Comment: That was my first guess but I `Cannot apply indexing [] to an expression of type IEnumerable<Foo>`. Instead I'll try `return CreateFooFromSelect(sql).GetEnumerator().Current;`

Answer (score 1):

Change the return type of CreateFooFromSelect to IEnumerable< Foo > - yield is used as a shorthand in methods that return IEnumerables. Then change foos.Add to foos.AddRange and you should be good.